# Onde remover esse aviso do visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Começou aparecer um aviso no meu Visual Studio 2015 que não tinha antes.

> Heap profiling is enabled in the Memory Usage tool. This impacts the performance of the process being debugged. It can be disabled from the Diagnostic Tools window.

Na mensagem tem um link "Open diagnostics Tools window" dizendo que pode ser desabilitado lá, mas achei opção para isso.

[image: aviso visual studio]

Já reiniciei o Visual Studio, já fechei a aba "Diagnostics Tools" e o aviso continua. Como remover isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Já desabilitou esta opção **Enable Diagnostic Tools while debugging**?
[Atualização] Requer o reinício do VS.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Deu certo, porém precisei reiniciar para sair a mensagem. Depois não apareceu mais. Edite a resposta dizendo que pode ser necessário reiniciar.